# Datagrid not displaying data from a new form

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a simple family card vb.net application with sqlexpress database. I am struck, please help:
When user save member, there are two Fields 1. Date of Birth, 2. Date of Baptism. He can skip both. So that I use the following statement:

```
If Not IsDate(DOBDatepik.Text) Then
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DOBDatepik.Value
            End If
```

it works. Now I create new form with Datagrid to find families.. Here is one statement when user Double click on any cell, a new form will display the current record. For that I use following statement:

I have not copied the whole text. This only for clarification

```
Private Sub familyGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles familyGridView.CellDoubleClick

        Dim int As Integer = Me.familyGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        FamilyDetails.DOBDatepik.Value = Me.familyGridView.Item(6, int).Value
        FamilyDetails.baptismDatepik.Value = Me.familyGridView.Item(12, int).Value
        FamilyDetails.Show()
    End Sub
```

it works, but where there is null date, it give the following error

```
Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

So please help me to resolve this. Null Date is not passing from DataGrid to new form, and Image which are as binary data in the table are also giving error while sending to new form.

Comment: Dont ask 2 questions in one post.  If someone only has time for one answer, you loose out.  You need to test for DBNull given the dates can be null.  Also you should use the event params, not `CurrentRow/CurrentCell`

Comment: I am sorry for that.... but DBNULL is not clear and how to use event params.. please explain.... if give code will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You issue seems to be when your passing the values over to the new for it looks like.

all you need to do is check if the values are null.

ex:

```
If Not Me.familyGridView.Item(6, int).Value is DBNull.Value Then
    FamilyDetails.DOBDatepik.Value = Me.familyGridView.Item(6, int).Value
Else
    FamilyDetails.DOBDatepik.Value = nothing
End If
If Not Me.familyGridView.Item(12, int).Value is DBNull.Value Then
    FamilyDetails.baptismDatepik.Value = Me.familyGridView.Item(12, int).Value
Else
    FamilyDetails.baptismDatepik.Value = nothing
End If
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks dear.. it works